# Data exchange between two pages with different domain. Firefox/Mozilla open new tab, NOT already opened window and DONT update data on page

Tags: javascript, mozilla, window.open

I am junior in javascript and try to solve issue with browser tabs.
It seems that situation is very simple. I have two pages with different domains.
From Page A I open page B in new tab. From Page B I send data to page A (using window.postmessage). When page B send data to page A, I suppose to open/ switch to opened tab of Page A
My code fine work for Chrome, but not for Firexox or IE11

NO Jquery!
**Page A code.**

```
 window.name = "pageA";
    var url = "https://test-a.page.eu";

//User call this functon by click on button    
function getAddress() {
        var win = window.open(url, "pageB");
        win.focus();
    }

    function setStorageParameters(data) {
        console.log("DATA");
        console.log(data.street);
        sessionStorage.setItem("streetAddress", data.street);
    }


    window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
        if (event.origin == url) {
            setStorageParameters(event.data);
        }
    });

    window.onload = function (e) {
        var streetAddress = document.querySelector("input[name='streetAddress']");

        if (sessionStorage.getItem("streetAddress") != null) {
            streetAddress.value = sessionStorage.getItem("streetAddress");
        }

        sessionStorage.removeItem("streetAddress");
    }
```

---

**Page B code.**

```
window.name = "pageB";
var openUrl = 'https://localhost:44388/';

function openChild() {

    //setTimeout(function () { sendMessage() }, 500);
    sendMessage();
}

function sendMessage() {
    var msg = {
        street: "Oru City",
    };

    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);

    if (isFirefox) {
        console.log("Firefox");
        childwin = window.parent.open(openUrl, "pageA");
        childwin.parent.postMessage(msg, openUrl);
        childwin.parent.focus();
    }

    if (isChrome) {
        console.log("Chrome");
        childwin = window.open(openUrl, "pageA");
        childwin.postMessage(msg, openUrl);
        childwin.focus();
    }
}
```

For localhost on server side (.net core 3) added code.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Default", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });
```

When I played with this code, it is strage, to see normal result when:
Page A(1) open Page B(1), Page B(1) send data and open Page A(2) in new tab. Page A(2) open page B(1), and it is correct that page B(1) open page A(2)

(1), (2) number of attempt
I am apologize for the complicated language :)

Any ideas to solve this issue for mozilla or IE?
I will be grateful for the answers

Comment: Have you tried if you can access the `A` tab from `B` using `window.opener` instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

Comment: Yes of cource. It is not work, because CORS, two diff domain. Actually, I have been worked with that documentation

Comment: Maybe it’s the same with window.open then, that might also be a security measure, that it doesn’t let you “overwrite” the content of tabs from a different domain.

Comment: Yes and no. Becouse it strats to work from 2 attempt. I need more research.

Comment: You mean it works then, for the _new_ tab that was opened on the first attempt? Well that _was_ opened _from_ `B` now, so I’d expect security to be relaxed _now_.

Comment: Yes, you are right, for the new tab Page B (1). 
So, why page A (1) have high security, but Page A (2) have a less security? Page B(1) we are open from same Page A, but from second attempt. Is it mean, that we set "same origin policy" for both pages in secondattempt?

Comment: The original tab A was not _opened by_ B, so I am guessing, you’re not allowed “access” to that. Your second A tab _was_ opened from B however. So that apparently gets treated differently, by the looks of it.